# Adding and removing classes from other divs after using jQuery fadeIn() in slideshow

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I've made a slideshow using jQuery. It uses the fadeIn and fadeOut methods. This works fine.

What I need help with is adding a css class to another div, depending on which slide is shown. I've added some shortened code to JSfiddle so you can get a better idea what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/dRqKM/

I want the pink boxes to become highlighted when the corresponding slide is shown.

Adding the following, doesn't seem to work:

```
if ($("#firstSlide").css("display") == "block") {
    $("#div1").addClass("Highlight");
    $("#div2").removeClass("Highlight");
    $("#div3").removeClass("Highlight");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three major problems:

1. The specificity of `.Highlight` is the same as `.button` and because `.Highlight` comes first in the CSS definition, the bg color from `.button` is winning out and keeping it pink.  Give it higher specificity or higher importance (e.g. `div.Highlight` or `.button.Highlight` or use `!important`)
2. Your code doesn't take into account rotation -- when you click the next/prev button.  So whatever turns green will just stay green because you're not rotating it.
3. your code that checks (the if/else if/else if block) was wrong.  The `if` looked ok but the other two condition blocks were wrong.  I'm going to assume that was just a demo typo.  But I fixed it in my example.

http://jsfiddle.net/dRqKM/1/  See this fiddle for a working version.  Note that if you want the box to turn **BEFORE** the fade ends, just move the call to `changeActiveChild` to be *after* the `fadeIn` call instead of inside the callback function, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/dRqKM/6/

Answer (score 0):

Those if statements you have will only be run once, on page ready, whereas you'll want them fired on click I'd imagine. Also your Highlight class doesn't have a high enough specificity to override the background style on the .button class. Consider this in your stylesheet:

```
div.Highlight { background:green; }
```

adding the node to the style rule will then override the button class's background.

Answer (score 0):

There were some logic issues I fixed here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dRqKM/7/

The biggest issue other than that was that the `.Highlight` class was declared before the `button` class so adding both of them, the `button` class still took precedence.  So even when the logic was right it wasn't working properly.  I moved the `.Highlight` class beneath the `button` class and fixed some logic.  Now you're all good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the class from all the buttons, then add it back to the proper one:

```
$('.buttons').removeClass('Highlight');
targetButton.addClass('Highlight');
```

Also, your `Highlight` class was not specific enough to override the `button` class. Another thing to note, use care if you intended `background-color: green;` rather than `background`. The `background` CSS property is used as a shortcut, and the syntax is different. If you're only specifying the color, the former method is usually preferred.

Here is a working version:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.slideshow').find('> li:eq(0)').nex\All().css({ 'opacity': '0', 'display': 'none' });
     $('.controls > a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var currentslide = $(this).parents('li:first');

        var currentposition = $('.slideshow li').index(currentslide);
        var nextposition = ($(this).attr('class') == 'next') ? currentposition + 1 : currentposition - 1;

        $('.buttons').removeClass('Highlight');
        $('#div'+(nextposition+1)).addClass('Highlight')

        $('.slideshow li:eq(' + currentposition + ')').hide() 
        $('.slideshow li:eq(' + nextposition + ')').fadeIn(2000);
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dRqKM/8/

**Documentation**

- `jQuery.addClass` - http://api.jquery.com/addClass/
- `jQuery.removeClass` - http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/
- jQuery Selectors - http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
- CSS `background` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background
- CSS `background-color` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-color

Answer (score -1):

Here you are mate: http://jsfiddle.net/zFnfC/

two lines on js and 1 on css

```
$("div.buttons").removeClass('Highlight');
$("#div" + (nextposition + 1)).addClass('Highlight');
```

and css:

```
.Highlight { background: green !important; }
```